# Regex stop Quantifer on True possible?

Tags: c#, regex

I wanna stop the Quantifier if the statment are true. any know how?

> XXXXXX, 20. September  2017 XXX XXXXXXXXX XX
>   MwSt. Nummer: CHE-XXX.XXX.XXX p.A. XXXXX XXXXXX XXXXX
>   Rechnungs Nr.321 XX XXXXX 32

```
XXXXXX, (?<Date>\d{2}.\s{1,}[A-z]{1,}\s{1,}\d{4})\s{1,}(?<CompanyName>.*)\n(?(?=Rechnungs Nr\.)Rechnungs Nr\.(?<BillNumber>\d{1,})|.*\n){1,}
```

My target is that:

```
XXXXXX, (?<Date>\d{2}.\s{1,}[A-z]{1,}\s{1,}\d{4})\s{1,}(?<CompanyName>.*)\n(?(?=Rechnungs Nr\.)Rechnungs Nr\.(?<BillNumber>\d{1,})|.*\n){2}
```

you see this is not dynamic and here is the problem. I wanna do it much times as possible. in some case `{2}` isnt enough. So i pick `{1,}`. The Problem here is the following text are match to. That is bad for me. I wanna do after that loop more loops for other text sequence. I only want match the digits ( in this example 321 ) After this Stop the if condition.

Thank you in advance.

[You can get Output here: Regular Expression](https://regex101.com/r/AJAaa3/1/)

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean? Please post some sample text and expected output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i have added some desciption. You can click the added link to get the Output :)

Comment: @Staubi: Do you mean this: https://regex101.com/r/AJAaa3/2 ?

Comment: @Jan Perfect, thank you alot. Can you description that? (?s:.*?) looks weird^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment (see the [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/AJAaa3/3)):

```
XXXXXX,\s*
(?<Date>\d{2}.\s+[A-Za-z]+\s+\d{4})\s+
(?<CompanyName>.*)(?s:.*?)
Rechnungs\ Nr\.(?<BillNumber>\d+)
```

Broken down this says:

```
XXXXXX,\s*                             # XXXXXX, followed by spaces
(?<Date>\d{2}.\s+[A-Za-z]+\s+\d{4})\s+ # your original expression
                                       # followed by at least one space

(?<CompanyName>.*)                     # rest of the line goes into
                                       # group CompanyName
(?s:.*?)                               # DOTALL, lazily
Rechnungs\ Nr\.(?<BillNumber>\d+)      # Rechnungs Nr.
                                       # followed by digits
```

Letting aside some potential optimizations, the main idea was to use

```
(?s:.*?)
```

Which turns on the `DOTALL` mode for a group, meaning that inside that group the dot matches *every charater* (including newline characters). With the lazy quantifier (`.*?`) it expands as needed, even across multiple lines.

As an alternative, you could use `[\s\S]*?` which combines whitespaces **and not whitespaces** leading to all characters in the end.

Side note: `\s{1,}` is the same as `\s+`, `\d{1,}` is the same as `\d+`, `[A-z]` includes more characters then `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: Great thank you, some questions: i have see you use flag (x) im not sure, work that on c#? I have try to add new regex, now it wont work. What you do if you add "Total inkl. MwSt. CHF 969.30" at the end and get 969.30?  Thanks for your time!

Comment: Bether say, how to add this: Total inkl\. MwSt\. CHF(?<Total>\d+.\d{2})  :)

Comment: @Staubi: The `x` flag makes an expression verbose and means spaces in the expression are ignored (and that you have to explicitly escape them in the expression itself). It surely works in `C#`.

Comment: Have found it. Yeah x flag works with c#. sry for this question. I never use flags so it confuse me little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found fast and good way:

```
XXXXXX, (?<Date>\d{2}.\s+[A-z]+\s+\d{4})\s{1,}(?<CompanyName>.*)\n(?(?!Rechnungs Nr\.).*\n)Rechnungs Nr\.(?<BillNumber>\d+)
```

[You can get Output here: Regular Expression](https://regex101.com/r/AJAaa3/5)